# "Undefined control sequence" error using handoutWithNotes

Tags: beamer, pdfpages

I'd like to print handout slides with `handoutWithNotes` package associated with `beamer`, but a simple try

```
\documentclass[handout]{beamer}
\usepackage{pgfpages}
\usepackage{handoutWithNotes}
\pgfpagesuselayout{2 on 1 with notes}[a4paper,border shrink=5mm]

\begin{document}
\begin{frame}
My first slide
\end{frame}
\begin{frame}
Second one
\end{frame}
\begin{frame}
Third
\end{frame}
\end{document}
```

returned me always the error message such as

```
! Undefined control sequence.
\@begindocumenthook ...ox { \vskip .05\pageheight
                                                  Notes\vskip .1\pageheight ...
l.8 \begin{document}
```

Apparently it comes with `\pgfpagesuselayout{2 on 1 with notes}[a4paper,border shrink=5mm]` "with notes" argument.

I run the file either with MiKTeX 2.8 or 2.9, either under Windows XP or Windows 10.

Comment: The package `handoutWithNotes` would appear to be somewhat uncommon. Is it available online? If so, where?

Comment: I get an error ``! LaTeX Error: File `handoutWithNotes.sty' not found.``.

Comment: I get the same error as the post owner!
@UlrikeFischer, you have to copy the package into your project folder or install it with MikTeX before you can use it

Comment: @Mico http://www.guidodiepen.nl/2009/07/creating-latex-beamer-handouts-with-notes/ that's where the package is from

Answer (score 2):

What fixed it for me was replacing `\pageheight` with `\paperheight` everywhere in `handoutWithNotes.sty`. See also https://github.com/gdiepen/latexbeamer-handoutWithNotes/pull/5.

Comment: Super helpful, thanks!